# Crstal Reports 8.5 and Temp Files

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

Scenario
1. Crystal Reports 8.5
2. Visual Studio 6

The above combination creates hundreds of .tmp files on drives and project directory folder on each time a project is compiled/run and I am sick of searching and deleting the temporary files.

Is this some sort of misconfiguration?
Does anybody know the secret of the .tmp files and how to avoid them?

Comment: Have you opened up the VB script yet?  That's probably how the original designer set it up.  And if you have the time, knowledge, and political clout to refactor it, go right ahead.  We're here to help!

Comment: If you don't want to refactor the original code (i.e. if it's not completely broken, don't fix it), you could write up a simple batch script to delete all the .tmp files for you. This would be much less invasive than refactoring.

Comment: There is an issue with VB6 IDE and ActiveX Designers that results in lots ot temp files. I'm using a batch that before starting VB6.exe cleans up the mess with temp and oca files.

Answer (score 1):

were you able to find a sensible approach to this issue? I run into the same situation when I developed an application using Crystal Report and VB6, somewhere in 2005, and the .tmp files were dumped straight onto my drive C. The only solution I could think of then, was to write a simple script in a batch file to clear all the temporary files generated, I must admit this wasn't the best of solutions since I had to click on that batch file anytime i see those plenty .tmp files.

Here is the content of the batch file, ClearTemp.bat, anyway:

```
echo "Temporary Files clearance in progress..."
@echo off
del "*.tmp"
```

Anyway, if you have found a better approach to this problem, do post it back so others could learn from it. 
Thanks.